# Oracle MDRT_#$ tables

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing, dbunit

Is it possible to configure Oracle to not use the "$" in the auto-generated MDRT table names? I am successfully using dbunit 2.5.4 to get the xml from my schema, but when I try to load the flat xml file into a dbunit dataset it fails because the xml contains element names (the MDRT table names) containing $, which can't be parsed by the xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the name, but I'm not sure why you would be querying the tables for anything? They are internal.  If you are querying the dictionary for a list of tables, then you should presumably exclude objects that are not explicitly created by yourself, eg USER_TABLES.SECONDARY